# Freeing dynamically allocated graph nodes in C

Tags: c, tree, free

I want to build a graph that creates a new parent node by merging two child nodes. The code below is supposed to merge node `a` and `b` into a parent node `c`. Then, nodes `a` and `c` to create a parent node `d`:

```
    a   b
    |---|
      |
  a   c
  |---|
    |
    d
```

When I try to free the graph starting at node `d` I get a segmentation fault and I don't know why. Somehow it works if I don't use the same node twice in the graph. However, I want to be able to use the same node more than once. Can someone please tell me what am I missing here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Node {

    int data;

    struct Node *child1;
    struct Node *child2;

};

struct Node *NewNode(double data) {

    struct Node *node = NULL;
    node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if (node == NULL) {
        return node;
    }

    node->data = data;
    node->child1 = NULL;
    node->child2 = NULL;

    return node;
}

struct Node* merge(struct Node *self, struct Node *other) {

    struct Node *node = NewNode(-1);
    node->child1 = self;
    node->child2 = other;

    return node;
}


void free_graph(struct Node **node) {
    if (*node != NULL) {
        free_graph(&(*node)->child1);
        free_graph(&(*node)->child2);
        free(*node);
        *node = NULL;
    }
}

int main(void){

    struct Node *a = NewNode(1);
    struct Node *b = NewNode(2);
    struct Node *c = merge(a, b);
    struct Node *d = merge(a, c);
    free_graph(&d);

}
```

Comment: Do you actually want to use the same node twice? Or do you want to use the same value twice?

Comment: @klutt I want to use the same node twice. Not exactly sure what you mean by value, though. From node `d` and `c` I need direct access to node `a`.

Comment: Well, then what you want is not a tree :)

Comment: Ok, probably it is a graph then? I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `a` into the intended tree twice, so `free_graph` attempts to free it twice. Calling `free` twice on the same address from the same original allocation is improper.

If you want to have a true tree, do not put any node into it twice. If you want to have a data structure that can have the same node in it twice, either use separate copies of the node (e.g., two different allocations for `struct Node` with the same value for `data`) or make provisions in the data structure to avoid freeing it twice (for example, add a reference count to `struct node` to count how many times it is currently in the tree, and free the node only when its reference count reaches zero).

Comment: I would like to have a data structure without making a copy as this would things more complicated further downstream. Not exactly sure how a reference counter works in C. I tried to set the pointer to a node `NULL` to avoid that it is freed more than once. Why does that not work in my case?

Comment: @Gilfoyle: Re “I tried to set the pointer to a node `NULL` to avoid that it is freed more than once. Why does that not work in my case?”: When the `a` as the child of `d` is being freed, `free_graph` calls itself recursively to free its children, one of which is `c`, and one of the children of `c` points to `a`. In that recursive call, the memory for `a` is freed. When the recursive calls complete, `free_graph` is still in the process of freeing `a`, and it calls `free(*node)` for `a`, but the memory for `a` has already been freed in a recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because your "tree" does not match your illustration, and is in fact technically not a tree. What you have looks like this:

[image: Directed graph]

You need to make a copy instead of reusing a node if you want a tree.

In order to free everything in a graph like this, I'd suggest having a separate linked list to keep track of everything you need to free.

If you don't want to do that, or cannot do that for some reason, it gets more complicated. Performing an operation an all nodes in a tree is trivial, but for a general directed graph it's slightly more complicated. I guess this answer could help, and if not, it at least gives you an idea about what to search for:

[Finding list of all nodes in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34329309/6699433)

I assume you could do something like this pseudo:

```
getAllNodes(root, nodes)
    if root // NULL check
        if not node in nodes // If it's the first time we visit the node
            // Add this node to the list of visited nodes
            nodes = nodes + [root]

            // And then call this function recursively on the children
            getAllNodes(root->left, nodes)
            getAlLNodes(root->right, nodes)

nodes = []
getAllNodes(root, nodes)
for node in nodes
    free(node)
```

Trees have the nice feature that they never contain loops. But directed graphs do, so you have to have some check to see if a node is already visited. Note that in order for this to work, it has to be called from the root. Or to be more precise, every node needs to be reachable from the node. But that's not so different from a tree.

I guess you could somehow move the free inside to create a `freeAllNodes()` function, but this is more flexible. Maybe you want a list for other purposes. So my suggestion in that case is to just make `freeAllNodes()` call `getAllNodes()`.

I could write an implementation for the above, but since C does not provide library functions for linked lists, that would mean including a lot of extra code.

Comment: What can I do that the graph I want to create matches my illustration? I would like to avoid making a copy as this would make things more complicated further downstream.